# Read / write load balancing with php - mongodb vs mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mongodb, caching

I have a system where users can 'like' content. There will likely be many hundreds of these likes going on at once. I'd like it to be AJAX driven so you get an immediate response.

At the moment I have a mysql table of `likes` which contains the `post_id` and `user_id` and I have a 'cached' counter on the `posts` table with the total number of likes - simple so far.

Would I benefit in any way, from storing any of this information in mongodb to take the load off of mysql?

At the moment, I click like, and two mysql queries run - and `INSERT into likes` and an `UPDATE on posts`. If I'm in a large-scale environment in heavy read/write situation what would be the best way to go?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you thought about using memcached or similar for the cached counter? It can easily be recreated, has low volume and is easily keyable.

Comment: This has very little to do with programming. The [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com) page would probably be a better place for a question like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL isn't a good option for something like this, as a large number of writes will cause scaling issues. I believe MongoDB's real advantage is schemaless JSON document oriented storage, and while it should perform better than MySQL (if set up correctly), I think you should look at using Redis to store counters like this (The single INC command to increase a number value is the cream on top of the cake). It can handle writes much more efficiently than any other database, as per my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, hmm ok so ideally you're saying to look at using Redis instead of Mongo for heavy writes?

Comment: @Tim For your specific purpose of storing the number of likes and the users who liked each item, I think redis works best. It isn't a full fledged database for storing more interrelated data though.